# git push failing with src refspec

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration

I am trying to push to github but its failing with following error

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/****'
```

I tried setting

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git push -u origin master
```

Still no success.

I am running git command on windows through cygwin.

Comment: Did you do: `git remote add origin git@github.com:YOURUSERNAME/repo-name.git`? What does your `git config --local -l` say?

Answer (score 3):

The message:

> ```
> error: src refspec master does not match any.
> ```

means that you don't *have* a `master` branch in your repository.

This is normal in a new, empty repository, since a new, empty repository has no commits, and a valid branch name must point to an existing commit.  With a universe of zero total commits, there is no valid commit for any branch name to identify, so no branch names can exist.

Despite the lack of any branch names, you're still *on* your (nonexistent) `master` branch in this new empty repository.  Creating a commit will *create* the branch, which you are on, and now everything is normal.

If you do have some commits, then, based on the error, you still have no `master`.  Getting into this state is a little more difficult, but not that hard: for instance, you can create an empty repository, use `git checkout -b` to set the current branch name to something other than `master`, and then make your first commit.  That will create some branch other than `master`.  Or, you might take an existing repository, switch away from the name `master`, then have Git delete the name `master` entirely, after which you no longer have a `master`.  Or, you might have used `git clone --single-branch` and chosen a branch other than `master`.  So as you can see, there are plenty of ways to get into this state.  It's not possible to tell which one(s) you used, just that you are in fact in this state.

Comment: Do you have a dev branch instead of a master? Find Your base branch and push to that instead of master.

Comment: I have `dev` & `master` branches with commits, both giving me same error.

Comment: @roy: add the output from `git branch` to your question, perhaps? And show the actual `git push` command as well as the subsequent error.